# ComboBox Selection not Updating Property on Model

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, combobox

I have a model called `PhoneRecords` that on it has two Properties, a `CostCodeId` (in the database) and a `CostCode` that is associated with it through the `CostCodeId`, created by Entity Framework. I have a ComboBox where the user can select a `CostCode` and I want them to be able to update it. This is the `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding AllCostCodes}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Text" 
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecord.CostCode}"/>
```

I update the `PhoneRecord` (SelectedRecord) like so:

```
using (var context = new DashboardContext())
{
    var original = context.PhoneRecords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == SelectedRecord.Id);
    if (original == null) return false;
    context.Entry(original).CurrentValues.SetValues(SelectedRecord);
    return context.SaveChanges() > 0;
}
```

Now when I delve into the `SelectedRecord`, after the User has chosen a different `CostCode` in the `ComboBox`, the `CostCode` property associated with the `PhoneRecord` has updated but the `CostCodeId` has not. As a result the `context.SaveChanges()` always returns 0 as it does not detect that the property has been updated.

My question is how can I align the `CostCode` selected on the `ComboBox` to both the `SelectedRecord.CostCode` and the `SelectedRecord.CostCodeId`?

EDIT: `PhoneRecord.cs` Generated by EF:

```
public partial class PhoneRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateGiven { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PhoneModelId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> NMU { get; set; }
    public string IMEI { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CostCodeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateReturned { get; set; }
    public string WhyReturned { get; set; }
    public string Solution { get; set; }
    public string Internet { get; set; }
    public string Provider { get; set; }
    public string SpeedDial { get; set; }
    public string OnDatabases { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual CostCode CostCode { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneModel PhoneModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't. It's one or the other. This logic should be implemented in the PhoneRecords class.

Comment: @mm8 Hmm ok so what kind of logic would I need to implement in the `PhoneRecords` class? Do I need to map the `CostCode` to the `CostCodeId`?

Comment: I did yes and that did work for me mapping the property to the combobox. So when the user opens the EditWindow it does load the correct `CostCode`, the issue now however is that when they choose a different one and click save, it does not update - I assume because EF is trying to update `SelectedRecord.CostCodeId` which hasn't changed, `SelectedRecord.CostCode` has.

Comment: @mm8 Sorry I don't understand. I implemented your solution and that fixed my issue in that question. This is a different issue now with updating,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ComboBox` control sets *one* property. This logic should be implemented in the `PhoneRecords` class. Something like this:

```
public partial class PhoneRecord
{
    private CostCode _costCode;
    public CostCode UiCostCode
    {
        get { return _costCode; }
        set
        {
            _costCode = value;
            CostCodeId = _costCode != null ? _costCode.CostCodeId : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My only issue is that my `PhoneRecord` class is automatically generated from the Database by EF. It's a partial class but how can I write something like the above even when it's generated by EF? I've updated my question with the class generated by EF.

Comment: Create a new property in another partial class with the above logic and bind to this one?

Comment: So I'll need to make a new CostCodeId and a new CostCode, bind the ComboBox to the new properties? I'll need to do this for every property that I want to bind to a ComboBox?

Comment: You create a new partial class like the one in my edited answer and then bind to the property in this one.

Comment: I've got it working but it seems like overkill to do this for every single property I want to use on a `ComboBox`. I will probably need to rethink what I'm doing and look at another approach.

Comment: Using auto-generated entity classes in a WPF application is seldom useful.

Comment: You would suggest not using EF? Or using code-first?

Comment: You can use EF for data retrieval in the data access layer. But you should bind to view models so you typically would need to map between entity classes and view models. But that's another story.